# Increasing the number of outbound TCP connections

Tags: linux, tcp, node.js, iperf

I am developing a small test client for websockets. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 . I have read 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux and I have done the following

```
sudo sysctl -w  net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10 
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65535"
```

As I understand these are for inbound connections and not outbound.

When I type

```
ulimit -n
unlimited
```

My client and servers run on different boxes. Even with all the above I am not able to cross beyound 1000 connections from a box . If there is a different tip let me know

**ANSWER**
I figured this by typing ulimit -a which shows all the kernel limits .

```
ulimit -n 
unlimited
```

while

```
ulimit -a
```

returns the value for nofile as 1024. I set the limits in the **/etc/security/limits.conf**file in the format

```
 <user> soft nofile 8192 
 <user> hard nofile 65000
```

and things worked for user

Comment: What I/O discovery method are you using? Is it select, poll, epoll, thread per connection, process pool, or what? And what goes wrong when you try to go over 1,000 connections?

Comment: I am using node.js socket.io-client . This internally is using a thread most probably . There is no error . netstat on the client and the server shows there are 1019 connections in the ESTABLISHED state  There are no error messages on the client or on the server

Comment: Are you sure you're typing `ulimit -n` from the exact same context in which node.js is launched?

Comment: I figured this by typing ulimit -a which shows all the kernel limits . ulimit -n returns unlimited while ulimit -a returns the value for nofile as 1024. I set the limits in the /etc/security/limits.conf file in the format ** <user> soft nofile 8192   <user> hard nofile 65000  and things worked

Answer (score 1):

I figured this by typing ulimit -a which shows all the kernel limits . ulimit -n returns unlimited while ulimit -a returns the value for nofile as 1024. I set the limits in the /etc/security/limits.conf file in the format **  soft nofile 8192  hard nofile 65000 and things worked